# Snowflake Snowsql conditional breaking IF, SWITCH

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Question is around Snowflake snowsql. And need to do a conditional check to see if an ETL_Date is already insert into a table and if it has; exit the stored proc. ELSE if date is not inserted go ahead and insert data and then return success(zero) and exit. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Starting Point: What I have done so far my code.

```
IF ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ETL_DATE),'1900-01-01') FROM DB.TABLES.test_20200909) > CURRENT_DATE() )
{RETURN 0; break;}
else insert into DB.TABLES.test_20200909 (ETL_DATE,INSERT_VALUE)
values(CURRENT_DATE(),1)
```

And this gives me error: **SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'IF'.**

Goal/End Game : Have to place this into a stored proc.
Which what I have put so far is:

```
CREATE or replace procedure   TABLE_DB.TABLES.test_20200909_1 ()
returns FLOAT
language javascript
as
$$

var test_1 =`IF ((SELECT MAX(ETL_DATE) FROM DB.TABLES.test_20200909) > CURRENT_DATE() )
{RETURN 0; break;}
else insert into DB.TABLES.test_20200909 (ETL_DATE,INSERT_VALUE)
values(CURRENT_DATE(),1)`;
var test_1_stmt =  snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: test_1});  
var test_1_res = test_1_stmt.execute();
return 0
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create a Stored Procedure to check/manage your load, I would create one like the following :

```
create or replace procedure SP_CHECK_LOAD()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
as $$    

function get_check_load()
{
    var v_out_check_load;
    rs = snowflake.execute ( { sqlText: `SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ETL_DATE)>=CURRENT_DATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CHECK_RESULT FROM DB.TABLES.test_20200909;` }  );
    if( rs.next())
    {
       v_out_check_load = rs.getColumnValue(1); // get check result
    }

    return v_out_check_load; 
}   
  
  var result = new String('Successfully Executed');
  var v_check = get_check_load();
  
  if ( v_check==1 )
  {
    //data not yet loaded -> load them
    try {
       
    var sql_command = `INSERT INTO DB.TABLES.test_20200909 (ETL_DATE,INSERT_VALUE) VALUES(CURRENT_DATE(),1)`;
 
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});
    var res = stmt.execute();  
    
    }
    catch (err) {
    result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + " | State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
    } 
 } // end if
 
 return result;

  $$;
```

Please note that I've used **>=** inside the check condition MAX(ETL_DATE)>=CURRENT_DATE() and not only > as in your example because in that case you would exclude current date load. Change it if this doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Saul I will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have mentioned, it looks like you don't even need a stored procedure to do this. You can use merge match which probably is more easier to setup

*And need to do a conditional check to see if an ETL_Date is already insert into a table and if it has; exit the stored proc. ELSE if date is not inserted go ahead and insert data and then return success(zero)*

Please see if below is what you are trying to achieve

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_20200909(INSERT_VALUE NUMBER, ETL_DATE TIMESTAMP);
 
INSERT INTO TEST_20200909 VALUES(1, '2020-09-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO TEST_20200909 VALUES(1, '2020-09-02 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO TEST_20200909 VALUES(1, '2020-09-03 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO TEST_20200909 VALUES(1, '2020-09-04 00:00:00.000');
 
SELECT * FROM test_20200909;
 
MERGE INTO test_20200909 T
 USING(SELECT MAX(ETL_DATE) maxdate FROM test_20200909) S 
 ON S.maxdate=CURRENT_DATE()
 when NOT matched then 
  insert (INSERT_VALUE,ETL_DATE)  values (1, CURRENT_DATE());
  
SELECT * FROM test_20200909;
```

Comment: Thank you @Rajib ; I will also try this out. I sadly do need a stored proc. As the solution i presented above is the most basic; there are other select logic statements after this IF clause that do an actual insert into a table.

Comment: Sure you can embed this merge query also in your procedure, will help you reduce code.  Let us know how you finally solve this.

Comment: Hi Rajib MERGE works just as fine; and was it MS-SQL ; would be the only way I would merge data. Sadly(and I do mean that), am migrating code to Snowflake. And business needs a stored proc.